# Can not print Nomenclature in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, nomenclature

I'm not able to run the following example in Texmaker:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\section*{Main equations}
\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%

\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%
The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
follows easily.

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

I use MiKTeX under Windows with the following Texmaker configuration:

[image]

and run the sequence:

[image]

I followed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154767#154767) to configure my editor without success. Thanks for your help

Comment: I have never used either nomencl or makeindex before but:  I just went to http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/nomencl/nomencl.pdf  and it is very clear that you need to run makeindex and not bib(la)tex.  Additionally you need the appropriate *.lst file.  So read the above reference and hopefully you will have success.

Comment: @R.Schumacher  Running `MakeIndex` gives me this error: `Input index file filename.idx not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]`

Answer (score 6):

Well , I created a new user command in Texmaker and I named it `MAKEINDEX`. The configuration of this new command is as follows:

[image]

As you see, I added

```
makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls
```

in the required command. Then, on my `main.tex` document, I run the sequence `pdflatex -> MAKEINDEX -> pdflatex` and it worked fine. Here is the output by the way.

[image]

I don't forget to thank R.Schumacher for directing me to re-read the documentation carefully.